# Preventing chrome extension to overwrite its source file

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser

I recently had to upgrade my chrome from 73 to 92 version. I used only one extension with a little bit of modification in the source code. It was working fine with version 73, however with version 92 my modification gets overwritten by each restart or more frequently.

Is there any way to prevent this overwriting? So I can modify the extension as my wish.

I guess this is a security feature, however I'd like to disable it as I use only this extension. How can I disable this feature?

The name of the extension is: Copy All Urls.

If it can't be disabled, is there any workaround? For instance creating a new extension from the original one with my modification? I'm very **unexperienced** with extensions... .

Thanks.

Comment: No. But you can copy your extension outside of the browser profile directory to your own directory, delete `_metadata`, then load it as an unpacked extension after enabling the developer mode switch on chrome://extensions page.

Comment: Yes, this is what I did exactly a few hours ago, but does it have a disadvantage to use the browser in the developer mode?

Comment: There is none, but you can disable this mode after you installed the extension.